# EventHandler member non-invocable as method

Tags: c#, events, methods, member

At Test.AEventHandler gives me error : non-invocable ... cannot use as method.
I cant see where I am wrong :( .

Can you tell me why is not working? Thanks!

```
Class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test first = new Test();
        first.send += Test.AEventHandler(onMessage);
    }

    public void onMessage(Message m)
    {
        Console.Writeln("It works!!!!");
    }

    ....
}

Class Test
{
    public delegate void AEventHandler(Message m);
    public event AEventHandler send;

    public void msg1(Message m)
    {
        if(send!=null)
            send(m);
    }

    ......
}
```

Note: Message is a type define by me...

If you can, please fix my code.

Comment: That's not your actual code.  `Class` would be a compiler error.  Post your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your `onMessage` method to `static` because `Main` method is static.You can't access a non-static method from inside `static` context:

```
public static void onMessage(Message m)
```

Then attach your event handler like this:

```
 first.send += new Test.AEventHandler(onMessage);
```

Or short version:

```
 first.send += onMessage;
```